# Store MySqlDataReader in a variable

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, webforms

I'm rewriting part of an old webforms application. I want to make a *central* function that will do the select queries. I will feed it the SQL query and parameters and it will do the rest.

So far I have this:

```
MySqlDataReader DoRead(string query, params MySqlParameter[] pms)
{
    MySqlCommand myCommand;

    if (!myConnection)
        myConnection = new MySqlConnection(sCon);

    if (myConnection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        myConnection.Close();
        myConnection.Open();
    }

    myCommand               = myConnection.CreateCommand();
    myCommand.CommandText   = query;
    foreach (MySqlParameter p in pms)
    {
        myCommand.Parameters.Add(p);
    }

    return myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
}
```

My question is, can I save the results of `myReader` to a variable and return that same variable instead of `myReader` just so I could close the connection and the reader immediately in the function instead in the *main* code?

Comment: Yes you can for sure. You can save the result set in a DataTable and return that DataTable instead. Alongside, I see few logical mistakes in your above posted code.

Comment: Short answer: yes. Just read all data from reader into, say, `DataTable` or `List<Something>`, close connection and return that datatable or list. But note - you should not store datareader itself, but read data from it and store data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course.  And that's exactly what you should be doing, for exactly the reason you state:

> so I could close the connection and the reader immediately in the function

The problem you're facing is the use of the reader in the first place, which itself is coupled to the open data stream.  So if consuming code is expecting a reader, it's going to have to change in order to fix this.

How does the application later use this reader?  If you're trying to make a generic function, then the result needs to be pretty generic too.  So if consuming code is all doing custom things with the reader then perhaps you can instead return a `DataSet` and consuming code can do custom things with that instead.  Something like this:

```
var result = new DataSet();

using(var myConnection = new MySqlConnection(sCon))
{
    myConnection.Open();
    var myCommand = myConnection.CreateCommand();
    myCommand.CommandText = query;
    foreach (var p in pms)
        myCommand.Parameters.Add(p);
    var myAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(myCommand);

    myAdapter.Fill(result);
}

return result;
```

(Note that I made another change here as well.  The *connection* object should also be local to the scope of the method.  Shared connection objects open up a world of potential problems, one of which you've undoubtedly tried to fix with that conditional to close/open the connection state.  Just avoid that world of problems entirely and dispose of connections once you're done with them.)